# Why my iOS app have too big size?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm developing native app for iPhone+iPad.
My app have just source code + images(~4mb, jpg).
But after building app's size is 48mb. 
What's the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: make sure that there is no iCloud data involved

Comment: maybe you could see some clues in the folders of the simulator?

Comment: How did you determine the appsize? Are you sure you are checkin the .ipa file?

Comment: @YunusNedimMehel, yes, i'm sure. 48.9mb:(

Comment: @BaSha iCloud is disabled

Comment: Just make "Clean"... Sorry guys:/